# How to customise the ion-select and ion-option menu (ionic)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

i am trying to get an ionic view such as this

[i want it ideally to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZld4.png)

[But right now i have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awqv6.png)

what do i need to change or add to get this layout, or is this design theme just a part of the android OS rather than ionic application?

if anyone knows how to fix this or what i need to do in order to change the look of the ion-select and ion-options menus i would really appreciate it.

SCSS

```
page-home {
.center {
display: block;
margin: auto;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.margins {
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
}
.ilb {
display: flex;
margin: 5px;
}
.curved {
margin-bottom: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
.curvedButton {
margin-left:10px;
margin-right: 10PX;
border-radius: 10px;
}

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="margins">
<form [formGroup]="todo" (ngSubmit)="CreateUser()" novalidate>
  <ion-item class="curved">
    <ion-label>Name</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="name"></ion-input>
    <p color="danger" ion-text *ngIf="todo.get('name').hasError('required')">*Required</p>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item class="curved">
    <ion-label>Company</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="company"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item class="curved">
    <ion-label>Room</ion-label>
    <ion-select #C (ionChange)="onChange(C.value)" id="roomFilter" formControlName="room">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let lab of labs" value="{{lab}}" type="string">{{lab}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item  class="curved" *ngIf="todo.get('room').errors && todo.get('room').dirty">
    <p color="danger" ion-text *ngIf="todo.get('room').hasError('required')">*Required</p>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item class="curved">
    <ion-label>PassID</ion-label>
      <ion-select formControlName="passID" multiple="true" id="passesID">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let pass of passes" value="{{pass}}">{{pass}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item  class="curved" *ngIf="todo.get('passID').errors && todo.get('passID').dirty">
    <p color="danger" ion-text *ngIf="todo.get('passID').hasError('required')">*Required</p>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item class="curved">
    <ion-label>Pass Return Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD MMM YYYY " min="2018" max="2030" formControlName="date" multiple="true">
    </ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
  <div class="ilb">
    <button class="curvedButton" ion-button block type="Reset">Reset Form</button>
    <button class="curvedButton" ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!todo.valid">Create</button>
  </div>
<ion-row style="height: 100px"></ion-row>
  <img alt="CC Logo" src="assets/imgs/Global Solutions Center_white.png" class="center" width="100%">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s the way it looks in iOS you can check it by open chrome dev tools and selecting and iOS phone it will look like that. I looked the ion selects docs and it says nothing for example about a mode property and change it to iOS so I don’t know if it’s really posible without change all the styles manually.